# Put flutter app in kiosk mode while on another app

Tags: flutter, kiosk-mode, system-alert-window

I want to make a screen lock application with flutter. How can I put it in kiosk mode when I'm on top of other applications? thanks

I tried showing an overlay with the system_alert_window package and running it there, but it didn't work.